# How to get public Ip address in Blazor Server Side

Tags: ip-address, blazor-server-side

I have Used https://api.ipify.org/?format=json this 3rd party api to get ip address but this had return ip address where the server is hosted which every user got same server ip.

I want to get public ip address for every user. Can anyone suggest me the solution?